# Hide softkeyboard on dialog box loading in Android 4.0

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, dialog

I have an `activity` which opens up a `dialog` that contains `edittexts` on a `button` click. As soon as the `dialog` opens the `softkeyboard` shows. I want to prevent this. Only when I click on the `edittext` in the `dialog` should the `softkeyboard` appear. I am using Android 4.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11732587/1436931) in your `Manifest ` file

Comment: thanks for the replay...sorry its not working in the case of dialogbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work is any case:

```
public void hideKeyboard() {

            mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) mActivity
                            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mActivity
                            .getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: This throws an NPE for me since getCurrentFocus() returns null. The answer by Mr. Bungle is better.

Comment: Instead of mActivity u need to pass your activity instance. But then whatever suits you better. :)

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this, set the soft input mode just before you call dialog.Show():

```
// Build and create your dialog.
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialogBuilder(...).create();

// Hide soft keypad by default (will be displayed when user touches any edit field).
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

// Show the dialog.
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score -1):

adding this to your Manifest is all you hav to do:

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"

Simple, but in case someone was looking here

:)

Comment: The user is asking about hiding the keyboard in a dialog, not in an activity

Comment: check the added answer wize